# $QQ$-plot - Why do we choose the empirical distribution $F_n(x) = \frac {\#\{y \in S \mid y \le x\}} n$, $S$ is sample, for comparison with normal?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

$QQ$-plot - Why do we choose the empirical distribution $F_n(x) = \frac {\#\{y \in S \mid y \le x\}}  n$, $S$ is sample, for comparison with normal ?

Let $S$ be our sample of size $n$. Then we form the empirical distribution  $F_n$ as defined above. We then use a $QQ$-plot to compare $F_n$ to $N(0,1)$ to see if there might be a linear relationsship.

1. Why do we choose $F_n$ as the emperical distribution for our sample ?
2. Could we get other results if we did not choose $F_n$ as the emperical distribution ?
3. For the fractile of $p \in (0,1)$ we choose the midpoint $x$ of the interval corresponding to $p$. Why do we choose the midpoint ?

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Just to mention that there is another SE site for statistics: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ is an i.i.d. sequence of $N(0,1)$-distributed random variables. If 
$$
F_n(x)=\frac{\#\{1\leq i\leq n\mid X_i\leq x\}}{n}=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}
$$
denotes the empirical distribution function then
$$
F_n(x)\to \Phi(x) \quad\text{almost surely as}\;n\to\infty,
$$
for all $x$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF of an $N(0,1)$-distribution.

This means that *if* you have an i.i.d. sample following an $N(0,1)$-distribution and $n$ is large enough, then $F_n$ must be "close" to $\Phi$. This is checked by plotting $F_n(x)$ against $\Phi(x)$ and checking if the points lie on the identity line.

Comment: Can this convergence of $F_n(x)$ to $N(0,1)$ be proven ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Yes, this is a consequence of the law of large numbers since $${\rm E}[F_n(x)]=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n {\rm E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}]=\Phi(x)$$

Comment: But what if our random variable was a coin with $50/50$ probability or a dice, then this would be false ?

Comment: Those aren't $N(0,1)$-distributed.

Comment: Oh so our assumption is that $X_i$ for $i = 1,2..$ are $N(0,1)$ distributed. And then we use the Law of Large Numbers to make a sequence of random variables that are $1$ if the appropriate event of $S$ happens for each of the values in our sample (that is $X \le k$ where $k$ is a sample value) ? And each of these sequences converge to the probability of the standard normal ?

Comment: More or less, so _if_ your sample was indeed from a normal distribution, then by the law of large numbers, the empirical distribution function would be "close" to $\Phi$ or in other words, the points in a QQ-plot would lie close to the identity line. This means that if your points does _not_ lie close to the identity line, then your sample cannot come from a normal distribution. The empirical distribution function is just a step function that, at each $x$, gives the frequency of how many in the sample that are less than $x$.

Comment: If $x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_n$ is your ordered sample, then $F_n(x)=0$ for $x<x_1$, $F_n(x)=\frac1n$ for $x_1\leq x<x_2$, $F_n(x)=\frac2n$ for $x_2\leq x<x_3$ and so on.

Comment: Sorry if I'm a little slow here. You view $F_n(x)$ as a random variable for every $x\in \mathbb R$ ? $F_n(x)$ is the sum of $n$ random variables (RV's that equal $1$ if the corresponding $N(0,1)$-RV has value less or equal than $x$, otherwise $0$) divided by $n$. Then the expectation of $F_n(x)$ indeed yields $\Phi(x)$ and from the sample $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ we obtain a realization (value) of every RV $F_n(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Correct! $F_n(x)$ is a random variable since, for fixed $n$, it's a function of the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. Another way to say it, is that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$: $F_n(x)=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$, where $Y_i=\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i\leq x\}}$. Now, $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ are i.i.d. with mean $\Phi(x)$ and by the law of large numbers $F_n(x)\to {\rm E}[Y_1]=\Phi(x)$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$. Note also that this argument works for any distribution (not just the normal distribution).

Answer (score 0):

The emipirical distribution function is the maximum likelihood estimator of the underlying distribution. Chosing anyting else will distort your data. The midpoint is chosen essentially by convention, since the empirical distribution is a step function. A simple example is the estimator for the median: if N=even, you are selecting the midpoint. Depending on the underlying distribution, (if you knew it), it might make more sense to take something besides the midpoint, but you will normally not have a good for doing something other than the midpoint.

Comment: How do you show the emperical distribution function is the maximum likelihood estimator ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen The actual proof requires Lagrange multipliers (see: http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~suhasini/teaching613/ED.pdf. )However, an intuiitively, the most likely distribution for an observed sample is one that looks exactly like the sample; hence, it will assign a probability of 1/N to each sample point, resulting in the empirical distribution function